# How to set GLOBAL hotkey in Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, global, msg

```
if (RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, MOD_ALT | 0x4000, 0x42))  //0x42 is 'b'
{
    qDebug() << "Hotkey 'ALT+b' registered, using MOD_NOREPEAT flag";
}

MSG msg = {0};

while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
{
    if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY)
    {
        qDebug() << "WM_HOTKEY received";
    }
}
```

This works, but this while loop freezes my application. I can't move it, etc. I tried with `QTimer` and set time to 100 and add to while a break at end, it works, but app has some lags. Is there another way to this right?

Comment: Why don't you use `installNativeEventFilter` function of QT? Here is an example https://github.com/mitei/qglobalshortcut

Comment: I used it. It works, but only if my app window is focused. I want to works even if there is hide window.

My simple code to test:

https://codepaste.net/7ud38v

Comment: EDIT .. It doesn't work. This space worked only. This shortcut doesn't work.